# Charging issues, carrera im2 bike

Tags: battery, charging

having charging issues with "wonderful" carrera impel 2 bike.
New battery fitted, software up to date, new charger as well. When i connect charger it's showing me that its charging on display (currently 33% charged, please see picture)
Been left over the night, no change, still on 33% (software been updated before charging) tried different chargers as well. Never had similar issues before.
Just wondering what have I missed. Or os it fault in general?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it this Halford's bike?  https://www.halfords.com/bikes/electric-bikes/carrera-impel-im-2.1-electric-hybrid-bike-microshift---s2fm-m2fl-frames-709830.html    Did you buy it new?   How old is it/how much distance has it done ?